# How to transform a map to a list?

Tags: java, java-8

What would be the easiest way to transform a map values to a list of objects (each map value contains that particlar object)?
Example program to demonstrate my problem is as follows.

```
public class MySubObject
{
  private int id;

  private String name;

  private int age;

  public MySubObject(int id, String name, int age)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name;
  }

  public int getAge()
  {
    return age;
  }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyTestMap
{
  public MyTestMap()
  {
    
  }
  
  public List<String> getNames(Map<Integer, MySubObject> inputMap)
  {
    List<String> outputList = new ArrayList();
    for(MySubObject eachObj : inputMap.values())
    {
      outputList.add(eachObj.getName());
    }
    return outputList;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    MySubObject obj1 = new MySubObject(1, "AAA", 10);
    MySubObject obj2 = new MySubObject(2, "BBB", 20);
    MySubObject obj3 = new MySubObject(3, "CCC", 30);
    
    Map<Integer, MySubObject> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, MySubObject>();
    myMap.put(obj1.getId(), obj1);
    myMap.put(obj2.getId(), obj2);
    myMap.put(obj3.getId(), obj3);
    
    // Need to extract names as a list. i.e. ("AAA", "BBB", "CCC")
    System.out.println(new MyTestMap().getNames(myMap));
  }
}
```

I know that logic inside getNames() method can be simplify to single line using Java 8 language features.
But need some help to start with.

Comment: `inputMap.values().stream().map(MySubObject::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want individual items , you can replace getName() with getAge() or getId(). If you want whole object to be stored in list, you can use the second example.

```
 // List of Names
    List<String> names = myMap.values()
            .stream().map(MySubObject::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(names);

    // List of objects
    List<MySubObject> mySubObjectsist = myMap.values()
            .stream().map(n -> n)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    mySubObjectsist.forEach(n -> {
        System.out.println(n.getId()
                + " " + n.getName() + " " + n.getAge() + " ");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8 stream**

**Concept here:**

You can convert given object to any type within the attributes types by using `map()` function by doing the stream operation over the collection and collecting it into a list. In your case, it will convert MySubObject object to String i.e `.map(MySubObject::getName)`

**Code:**

```
myMap.values().stream().map(MySubObject::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```